# MIPS discard uppercase or non-alphanumeric

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to write a program that will put lower case letters entered from the console into alphabetical order.  It must discard upper case letters and any non-alphanumeric.  This is what I have so far.  It works OK but I still need to implement the code to remove uppercase and non-alphanumeric.  Any ideas on how I can implement that into this program?  Thanks!

Oh and one more thing.  When I run this program as is it creates a new line for the answer, for example.

It should say

```
Please type the letters: cba*
The alphabetized string is: abc
```

Instead it says

```
Please type the letters: cba*
The alphabetized string is: 
abc
```

Anyway here it is.

```
# $t0 -- Pointer to current spot in letters
# $t1 -- Holds the "upstream compare character"
# $t2 -- Holds the current character being analyzed
# #t7 -- Pointer to the first character in string
#### Data Segment ####
.data
letter_prompt:  .asciiz "Please type the letters: "
output_message: .asciiz "The alphabaetized string is: "
inputString:    .space 30   # space for input string
        .text
main:
la $a0,letter_prompt    #print prompt string
li $v0,4
syscall
la $a0,inputString  #read the input string
li $a1,30       #at most 100 characters
li $v0,8
syscall
la $t0,inputString
la $t7,inputString
j loop
loop:
lb $t1,0($t0)       #Load first two characters to be compared
lb $t2,1($t0)
beqz $t2, exit_loop     #if NULL, we are done
blt $t1,0x61,no_change
bgt $t1,0x7a,no_change
ble $t1,$t2,no_change
jal rev             #Characters not in correct order; go to reverse
j loop          #Character in correct position; get next character
no_change:  addi $t0,$t0,1      #increment character
j loop
exit_loop:  la $a0,output_message   #output sorted string
li $v0,4
syscall
li $v0,4
la $a0,inputString
syscall
li $v0,10       #exit program
syscall

#Character reverse routine
rev:
sub $sp,$sp,4       #Store contents of $ra on the stack
sw $ra,($sp)        #Decrement stack pointer.
sb $t1,1($t0)       #Exchange two character positions
sb $t2,0($t0)
beq $t0,$t7,goBack  #if at first position in the string, done
sub $t0,$t0,1       #Decrement the letter pointer
lb $t1,0($t0)       #Compare the letter to next "upstream" letter
lb $t2,1($t0)
ble $t1,$t2,goBack  #If letter is properly placed, done
jal rev         #Not done yet; move back another position
goBack:
addi $t0,$t0,1      #Reverse done; move back to current position
lw $ra,($sp)
addi $sp,$sp,4
jr $ra
```

Why does it look like this?  How do I get it into regular format?

Comment: Indent 4 spaces instead of using backticks for code blocks (in fact, avoid backticks in general).  You had inserted many blank lines so the backticked lines would be on separate lines, and you may need/want to reformat the code after my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ASCII code.[ASCII](http://www.cs.utk.edu/~pham/ascii.html)